# the interaction of wordlist and top features selected based on weights

Tags: rapidminer

In the training process for a text classification case, the wordlist generated from `process document`module has a length of about 15000 words. On the other side, I applied feature selection module, i.e.,`weight by information gain` and `select by weight` to select top 500 features. Both wordlist and selected weights are stored. Are there any ways to apply this generated 500 weights to the wordlist and constructed the short wordlist, which exactly matches the 500 weights. In other words, I would like to have the intersection of the original wordlist (about 15000 words) and the top 500 features(or top 500 words based on the ).

The following shows the script I am using.The stored weight(circled with red) is two columns where the first column is word(attributed) and the second column is corresponding weight value. Based on which, we can select top 500 or any other top features. The original wordlist (circled with red) can have 15000 words, a matrix with 15000 rows.

My question is that how to generated a filtered wordlist object based on the ranked weight object.

I have posted this question on [Rapidminer forum](http://community.rapidminer.com/t5/RapidMiner-Studio/generate-a-subset-of-wordlist-based-on-a-given-weight-table/td-p/33270). Please follow the update there.

Answer (score 0):

You should post a representative process. In the absence of that it's difficult to give help but my view is that you could take the 500 word example set and process it again to make a word list from it.

Comment: I have updated my original post based on your suggestion.

Comment: I answered this in the RapidMiner forum. It would be worth linking to this so others can benefit.

Comment: Thanks, link is included in the original post.